# AppcompatDialog and Fragment in Android

Tags: fragment, appcompatdialog

I want to use AppCompatDialog in place of DialogFragment.
Is there any way to do without removing the Fragment part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a AppCompatDialogFragment so it seems you can use this